# Full Auto Gun Audio

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, game-development

Currently I have a script that plays a gun shot sound and a gun shot tail sound when the gun is fired, but if I keep shooting the gun after a while the gun shot sounds sound corrupted which I think is because of the 32 sounds threshold and so I want to know how to do full auto gun audio without it having performance issues.

Comment: How did you play a gun shot sound?

Comment: AudioSource.PlayOneShot();